# Compiling SCSS makes over 3 MB CSS file

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I have a react app (using create-react-app). I wanted to add SCSS to my project so I ejected from the prebuilt config files.

The issue I'm facing here is that after I ran my build (for prod), it compiled everything down to 3.3 MB. Usually, CSS is not more than 300 KB. I was very surprised by that.

Not sure what's the best thing to do here to provide you for more details. I can show you the files I'm importing in my main SCSS file.

```
/*Direction */
// Override default value for $dir in directional
$dir: ltr;

// Import helpers from directional
@import "../base/directional";

@import "../base/variables";

// Import helpers from bootestrap
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/root";
@import "bootstrap/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/type";
@import "bootstrap/images";
//@import "bootstrap/code";
@import "bootstrap/grid";
//@import "bootstrap/tables";
@import "bootstrap/forms";
//@import "bootstrap/buttons";
@import "bootstrap/transitions";
@import "bootstrap/dropdown";
@import "bootstrap/button-group";
@import "bootstrap/input-group";
@import "bootstrap/custom-forms";
@import "bootstrap/nav";
@import "bootstrap/navbar";
@import "bootstrap/card";
//@import "bootstrap/breadcrumb";
//@import "bootstrap/pagination";
//@import "bootstrap/badge";
//@import "bootstrap/jumbotron";
//@import "bootstrap/alert";
//@import "bootstrap/progress";
@import "bootstrap/media";
@import "bootstrap/list-group";
@import "bootstrap/close";
@import "bootstrap/modal";
//@import "bootstrap/tooltip";
//@import "bootstrap/popover";
@import "bootstrap/carousel";
@import "bootstrap/utilities";
//@import "bootstrap/print";

//select2-develop
@import "../select2-develop/core";

/* slick slider component*/

@import "../modules/slick";
/* BASE - Base styles , variables, mixins, etc*/
@import "../base/mixins";
@import "../base/normalize";
@import "../base/base";

/*MODULES  - Individual site components */
@import "../modules/typography";
@import "../modules/blocks";
@import "../modules/buttons";
@import "../modules/checkbox";
@import "../modules/list-group";
@import "../modules/components";
@import "../modules/select";
@import "../modules/sections";
@import "../modules/title";
@import "../modules/dialog";
@import "../modules/social-media";
@import "../modules/renderField";
@import "../modules/selectInput";
@import "../modules/renderFileInput";
@import "../modules/number_picker";
@import "../modules/product_grid_view";
@import "../modules/product_list_view";
@import "../modules/customer_service";
@import "../modules/render_products";
@import "../modules/_scroll_to_top";
/* LAYOUTS - page layout styles */

@import "../layouts/nav";
@import "../layouts/header";
@import "../layouts/manual-form";
@import "../layouts/home-details";
@import "../layouts/products";
@import "../layouts/product";
@import "../layouts/apps-link";
@import "../layouts/authentication/login";
@import "../layouts/authentication/signup";
@import "../layouts/tyres/tyres";
@import "../layouts/category/motor-oil";
@import "../layouts/tyres/tyres-search";
@import "../layouts/vehicles/vehicles";
@import "../layouts/setting/wish-list";
@import "../layouts/setting/setting";
@import "../layouts/garage-popup";
@import "../state/checkout/cart";
@import "../state/checkout/order_summary.scss";
@import "../layouts/quotation-request";
@import "../layouts/send-request";
@import "../layouts/search_result";
@import "../layouts/authentication/forgot-password";
@import "../layouts/authentication/confirm-signup";
@import "../layouts/authentication/email-verification";
@import "../layouts/footer";
@import "../layouts/setting/profile";
@import "../layouts/setting/reset-password";
@import "../layouts/setting/garage";
@import "../layouts/setting/orders";
@import "../layouts/setting/payment";
@import "../layouts/setting/addresses";
```

If my webpack setup in important as well, I can provide that too. Thank you guys so much for your time, I appreciate it.

**Update**

Here is what I am talking about what it creates after running npm run build:

[image]

**Update 2**

The issue I had was that SCSS was creating so much nesting for simple things. Like there was over a 50 line of nesting just to add a simple padding. Here is what I mean:

```
.form-control-plaintext.form-control-sm, .input-group-sm > .form-control-plaintext.form-control,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.input-group-text,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.input-group-text,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-primary,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header #footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#footer .list-unstyled a #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header #mobile-footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-footer .list-unstyled a #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-facebook,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-google,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .product-buttons .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-detail,
.product-buttons #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-detail,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .product-buttons .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-cart,
.product-buttons #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-cart,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-secondary,
#custom-details .custom-container .parts-container .number-picker-container #number-picker .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > input.form-control-plaintext,
#number-picker .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > input.form-control-plaintext,
#number-picker .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-negative,
#number-picker .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-positive,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-gray-secondary,
#cart .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.back-shop,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-gray,
.quantity .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > button.form-control-plaintext,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-primary,
#footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#login .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-signin,
.product-buttons .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-cart,
.product-buttons .input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-detail,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-google,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-facebook,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-primary,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header #footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#footer .list-unstyled a #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header #mobile-footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-footer .list-unstyled a #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-facebook,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-google,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .product-buttons .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-detail,
.product-buttons #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-detail,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .product-buttons .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-cart,
.product-buttons #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-cart,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-secondary,
#custom-details .custom-container .parts-container .number-picker-container #number-picker .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > input.form-control-plaintext,
#number-picker .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > input.form-control-plaintext,
#number-picker .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-negative,
#number-picker .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-positive,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-gray-secondary,
#cart .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.back-shop,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-gray,
.quantity .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > button.form-control-plaintext,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-primary,
#footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#login .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-signin,
.product-buttons .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-cart,
.product-buttons .input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-detail,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-google,
.input-group-sm > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-facebook, .form-control-plaintext.form-control-lg, .input-group-lg > .form-control-plaintext.form-control,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.input-group-text,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.input-group-text,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-primary,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header #footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#footer .list-unstyled a #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header #mobile-footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-footer .list-unstyled a #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-facebook,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-google,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .product-buttons .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-detail,
.product-buttons #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-detail,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .product-buttons .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-cart,
.product-buttons #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-cart,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-secondary,
#custom-details .custom-container .parts-container .number-picker-container #number-picker .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > input.form-control-plaintext,
#number-picker .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > input.form-control-plaintext,
#number-picker .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-negative,
#number-picker .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-positive,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-gray-secondary,
#cart .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.back-shop,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-gray,
.quantity .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > button.form-control-plaintext,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-primary,
#footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#login .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-signin,
.product-buttons .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-cart,
.product-buttons .input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-detail,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-google,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-prepend > .form-control-plaintext.btn-facebook,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-primary,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header #footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#footer .list-unstyled a #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header #mobile-footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-footer .list-unstyled a #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-facebook,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-google,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .product-buttons .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-detail,
.product-buttons #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-detail,
#mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .product-buttons .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-cart,
.product-buttons #mobile-header-details .dropdown-header .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-cart,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-secondary,
#custom-details .custom-container .parts-container .number-picker-container #number-picker .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > input.form-control-plaintext,
#number-picker .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > input.form-control-plaintext,
#number-picker .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-negative,
#number-picker .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-positive,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-gray-secondary,
#cart .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.back-shop,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-gray,
.quantity .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > button.form-control-plaintext,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-primary,
#footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#mobile-footer .list-unstyled a .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > i.form-control-plaintext[class*=icon-],
#login .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-signin,
.product-buttons .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-cart,
.product-buttons .input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-detail,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-google,
.input-group-lg > .input-group-append > .form-control-plaintext.btn-facebook {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the you are importing everything including generic CSS, feature specific CSS, images & fonts in single file, even though not all of it is required in initial load.

This creates a huge JS bundle which includes all 
CSS, images & fonts(Thats why your bundle size is 3mb, try building production version using `yarn build` and check the size again).

Move feature specific CSS to its respective JSX files and lazy load JS bundles using dynamic import. this should optimize bundle size a lot.

Also `create-react-app v2` has `SCSS` support, try if you can upgrade instead of ejecting.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can't undo the eject anymore. If I go back to a previous version, there is so much stuff I having to redo.

I think you misunderstood me. I meant that the CSS file that was created after running `npm run build` is 3 MB itself (main.css). Is it supposed to be that big?

Comment: I've attached an image of what I'm talking about. Thank you again

Comment: Can you open your css file and check for inlined base64 encoded images and fonts? this could be the reason for the size problem. you could extract them as separate assets using webpack `file-loader`.

Comment: I've just checked. The biggest base64 encoded image I have is just 9KB. I don't think that's the issue here.

What other suggestion do you have? Could it be that SCSS has a poor performance

Comment: I can't think of anything else, but just check if your CSS(if minified, beautify it) and check for duplicate CSS or any unnecessary stuffs present. Also both `main.css` and `style.css` has same contents?

Comment: I found out the issue I had. I'll post my answer now. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I've updated my question. Any suggestion on what I could do to fix that? Like I didn't do it intentionally. I think when I used the `extend`, it had to add that much for me.

Comment: Probably you are extending a lot from bootstrap classes, so its bringing entire bootstrap classes nesting to your classname and its copying entire bootstrap styles into your class, which might be redundant. Try avoiding extending from bootstrap class, instead use you custom classname with normal bootstrap class. Eg: `#mobile-header-details > .form-control-plaintext.btn-primary { ... }`

Comment: Cool, I'll try that then. Thank you

Comment: I just removed all the extends I have in the project. Now everything works smoothly and it even compiled it down to 16 KB XD.

I'm just gonna copy past CSS instead and never extending from bootstrap